# how to multiply particular type of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose you have $B =\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\
3 \\
5
\end{bmatrix}$ , and  $A =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
5 & 6
\end{bmatrix}$ . I want a resulting matrix $C =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\
9& 12 \\
25& 30
\end{bmatrix}$ . What is the matrix operation between A and B that results in C. I essentially want to multiply B by A so each entry in A is multiplied by the scalar in B.

Comment: Are you asking for the name of the operation? You seem to describe it well. Multiply each entry in a given row of $A$ by the corresponding scalar in the same column of $B$. I think in MATLAB, for instance, you can achieve this using the '.*' operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to multiply each row $i$ of $A$ by $B[i]$, then direct matrix operations won't do that; however you can instead left-multiply $A$ by a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are taken from $B$:
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&5\end{pmatrix}
\qquad\text{indeed}\qquad
  \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&5\end{pmatrix} \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\\5&6\end{pmatrix}=
  \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\9&12\\25&30\end{pmatrix}.
$$